# Styled Components warning for dynamically imported React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

From a headless CMS I'm fetching the list of components which should be included on certain page. Once fetched, I dynamically import mentioned components like this:

```js
const components = ["Test", "Test2"]; // comes from CMS

const DynamicComponent = ({ name }) => {
   let Component;
   Component = require(`./components/${name}`).default;
   return <Component />;
};

export default function App() {
   return (
      <Container>
         {components.map((comp, i) => (
         <DynamicComponent name={comp} key={i} />
          ))}
      </Container>
   );
}
```

And then I just pass these component as children props to some container.

However, although everything works fine, I'm getting some warning for every component I have that says:

> The component styled.div with the id of "sc-bdnylx" has been created dynamically.
> You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
> To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.

I googled the warning but everywhere the solution is to not define styles within the component. I could be wrong, but I don't think that's applicable here.

Here's the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/style-components-dynamic-5id3y?file=/src/App.js (check the console output)

How can I get rid of this warning?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the warning is pretty clear when it says "create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and **function component**". So what you can do is refactor your functional component `DynamicComponent` into a class based component

```
class DynamicComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Component = require(`./components/${this.props.name}`).default;
  }
  render() {
    return <this.Component />;
  }
};
```

EDIT: tested on your sandbox, made the fixes to my previous code, and your warnings are gone